# The use of distributions in solving differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

In David Eisenbud and Joe Harris's book "The Geometry of Schemes", they say some method in algebraic geometry is analogous to the use of distributions in analysis.

> In trying to construct a certain scheme, it is often easy to construct the functor that would be the functor of points of that scheme, if the scheme existed; the construction problem is then reduced to the problem of proving that the functor is representable and the use of Yoneda's Lemma (VI-1). The process is exactly analogous to the use of distributions in analysis: there, when trying to prove the existence of a nice function solving a given differential equation, one first proves the existence of a solution that is a distribution, and then is left with the (possibly more tractable) regularity problem of proving that the distribution is represented by integration against a function

I am interested in this process they describe.
I know little about differential equations, so I don't know how it work.
Are there any books or papers giving this process with easy examples?

Comment: Not exactly as deep as the claim: In the existence proofs for ODE you first prove the existence of a continuous function as fixed point, then explore its smoothness. Using that downgrading from $C^1$ to $C^0$ is a compact mapping. Or in variational calculus you reduce (some) second-order linear DE with boundary conditions to minimizing a variational integral over $H^1$, find the solution as $H^1$ (or even $H^{-1}$?) generalized functions, and after that prove that solutions are actually in $C^2$.

Comment: Basically any book on PDE beyond just explicit solutions by Fourier series or the like will get into this. Evans is probably the standard place to start though it seems like it doesn't lean on distributions as heavily as it possibly could. But for purposes of understanding this analogy, you don't really need the details. The idea is simple: if we had something with property A, it would have property B also; show something out there has property B, then if only one such thing exists, show it has property A, after you already have it.

Comment: In DE my property A is satisfying the original equation and my property B is the weak formulation, which you get by doing some manipulations on the equation that are reversible if you have enough regularity but in general are not reversible.